# Error: Authentication failed while connecting with mongodb in r

Tags: r, rmongodb

Trying to connect MongoDB on local machine using rmongodb

`mongo <- mongo.create (host='127.0.0.1', username = "admin", password = "admin123", db = "admin")`

> Error: Authentication failed

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, R version 3.4.4 and MongoDB version: 3.2.19?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the password and username is correct? Also is the serve behind a firewall or requires VPN?

Comment: @Amar yes sure its correct.

Comment: What about the database, where is it located/is it behind a firewall? Can you access it from a different location/device?

Comment: @Amar I am connecting to local network, and I am trying to access on local machine.

Comment: You have not specified what package you are using to access mongodb, going to guess it's `rmongodb` which appears to have an issue as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664719/rmongodb-authentication-always-fails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rmongodb authentication always fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664719/rmongodb-authentication-always-fails)

Comment: @Amar yes using rmongodb and also I have checked those links but problem is not solved. I have done this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664719/rmongodb-authentication-always-fails

Comment: As the link says `rmongodb` is not compatible with the latest version of mongodb. Either: 1. Work without authentication 2. Downgrade the MongoDB server version to one that supports the old authentication 3. Look for other driver implementations that support the new authentication.